# Как в Android Studio у существующего проекта поднять версию ОС устройства?

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день, пишу в Android Studio под версию устройства Android 4 как можно в этом же проекте поднять версию до Android 6 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если имеется в виду минимальная поддерживаемая версия ОС, то укажите её в `build.gradle` `(module app)`. Вам требуется изменить значение переменной `minSdkVersion` в блоке `defaultConfig` на `23`

Comment: а почему 23 у меня присвоено 16 а не подскажете ещё targetSdkVersion 23 за что отвечает ?

Comment: @VargSieg, первую часть вопроса совсем не понял, а второе - это типа та версия ОС на которой приложение гарантированно должно работать. Т.е. если вы его обновлять не будете, а ОС будет обновляться, то с вас никто не спросит за неработоспособность на 10 андроиде, если у вас указан 6-ой как targetSdkVersion

Comment: В первой части вопроса я имел ввиду почему 23 == 6-ой версии где посмотреть градацию ?

Comment: @VargSieg, вот тут есть таблица соответствия уровня API и версии ОС https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html